# AddDbContext not available in IServiceCollection in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I have .NET Core 2 project in Visual Studio 2017. I am trying to add (Postgresql) database connection. Here is a code:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext(options =>
        options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc();
}
```

But compiler complains with this message:

> IServiceCollection does not contain a definition for 'AddDbContext'
>   and no extension method 'AddDbContext' accepting a first argument of
>   type 'IServiceCollection' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

I installed NuGet package Npgsql. I also tried to install NuGet package EntityFramework, but I'm receiving error:

Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'MyProject'.

Is this the root of my problem? Should I install some other library?

On this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37569990/iservicecollection-does-not-contain-a-definition-or-extension-for-addnpgsql) procedures AddEntityFramework() and AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql() are used, but those two are also not recognized by compiler in my project.

Comment: Do you have appropriate using statements for the entity framework namespace on the top of your code?

Comment: @calingasan: compiler is not suggesting that using statement is missing. Instead, only available suggestions are to Generate Class.

Comment: Well yes, the error message is suggesting that a using statement is missing.

Comment: This seems like something that can happen in a multiproject solution. Bear in mind, that if your startup.cs project is depending on another project in a solution (where maybe the EntityFrameworkCore library resides), you will have to compile the dependency first and then see if it is all right. In any circumstance, you need to put a using statement into the main project startup.cs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I installed Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL and that resolved my issue. I also used Danijel's suggestion:

```cs
services.AddDbContext<ClassDbContextName>(options =>
            options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Answer (score 34):

Make sure you installed related NuGet packages with the right version for example

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore v3

and are using the right namespace such as

> using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
>
> using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

Answer (score 3):

Adding using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection fixed this issue for me.

Comment: This should be a comment more than an answer (from review).

Answer (score 2):

In case your persistence layer is in another project (`Class Library`) and you have installed an appropriate NuGet library like  `Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL` on the persistence layer, Then a `build` is necessary, especially if you are using `VS Code`. otherwise, it may not recognize `services.AddDbContext<T>`

Answer (score 0):

try this

services.AddDbContext(options =>
options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")))

Comment: tnx it give a solution

Comment: Use correct spelling, punctuation, and grammar to the best of your ability.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is very simple you just have to install microsoft.entityframeworkcore nuget package in the right file. then After the installation the intellisence help the option will be visible to you.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue with **Sqlite**.

1. I installed **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite** from **Nuget galary**.
2. I installed the package under the folder inside of which **StartUp.cs** file is located.
3. Introduced **using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore** inside **StartUP.cs**

This solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

for ASP.Net core, from command prompt.

dotnet add package Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL

for installing specific version,
dotnet add package Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL --version 6.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command to add the specific version of PostgreSQL package to your project

```
dotnet add package Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL --version 6.0.0
```

The following command will add the latest package.

```
dotnet add package Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL
```

Answer (score 0):

Same issue after fresh installation EntityFrameworkCore.SQLServer and Design on Visual Studio 2022.

Restarting Visual Studio did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

For .net core 6 it was needing `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using VS Code with multiple projects:

Target the project in which you've added Entity Framework.

For Windows:

1. Ctrl+Shift+P
2. OmniSharp: Select Project (select the project in which you added Entity Framework)

Answer (score 0):

Here are the packages to install via Nuget, as per [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-8.0)

To sum it up:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

var app = builder.Build();
```

Answer (score -2):

Could you please try like this

```
services.AddDbContext<ClassDbContextName>(options =>
        options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Comment: Yes. There is same message. You can remove your answer.

Comment: What is ClassDbContextName? Should I also add definition for that?

Comment: ClasssDbContexName is just name of class but it referring to database tables and so on. If you check this link you will see an example.
Hope it is useful for you:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/new-db